# if ID equals param not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to collect all the clients of my current group_id in json (/groups/1/clients.json)

I'm using a custom method because I want all the groups of the `current_user` aswell.

Anyway; I have a method that checks in a loop of all the groups of current_user if the `params[:group_id]` equals the group.id of my loop. And if it is; Output my clients in a JSON file.

Now I'm 100% positive that `params[:group_id]` and `group.id` exist(I've both been able to output them into the JSON if I escape the `if params[:group_id] == group.id`.

Nonetheless, when I'm using the IF statement I don't get the output I need. Does anyone have any clue why my IF statement doesn't go as I was expecting?

```
@usersGroups = current_user.groups
if params[:group_id]
  @usersGroups.each do |group| 
    if group.id == params[:group_id]
      respond_to do |format|
          format.json { render json: group.clients, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: params are generally strings

Comment: Can I parse one of both to either a string or int?

Comment: safest is to stringify the group's id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
group.id.to_s == params[:group_id]
```

Also you can clean up your code like this:

```
group = Group.where(user_id: current_user.id).find(params[:group_id])
respond_to do |format|
  format.json { render json: group.clients, status: :unprocessable_entity }
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the edit; I'm using the same method without a group_id though. (To get 'all' the groups of the user)